# How to change array in struct to pointer in C

Tags: c

I had stuct and my function:

```
#define MAX 4096
typedef struct{
   char comment[40];
   int nbpts;
   float time[4096];
   float value[4096];
} trace;
void simuTrace(int tmax, float dt, float params[], trace* uneTrace){
    int i = 0;
    float v = 0, w = 0, dv = 0, dw = 0, t = 0;
    while (t<tmax && i < MAX){
        dv = (params[0]-v)*(v-1)*v - w;
        dw = params[4]*(params[1]*v-params[2]*w-params[3]);
        v += dv*dt;
        w += dw*dt;
        uneTrace->time[i] = t;
        uneTrace->value[i] = v;
        i++;
        t += dt;
    }
    uneTrace->nbpts = i+1;
    uneTrace->comment[40]= "CommentaireDeLaTrace";
}
```

and I want to change struct here, it's not limit MAX but I don't know how to make. how to change some value in function by the new struct>

```
typedef struct{
    char comment[40];
    int nbpts;
    float *time;
    float *value;
} trace;
```

Comment: Don't you get compiler warnings? What about `uneTrace->comment[40]= "CommentaireDeLaTrace";` This writes an incompatible value (`char *` pointer to `char`) out of the bounds of the array. Use `strcpy` to copy a string.

Comment: You can't assign to an array, that should be `strcpy(uneTrace->comment, "CommentaireDeLaTrace")`

Comment: Please use the `MAX` from `#define MAX 4096` and not hard code `4096`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `malloc`

```
typedef struct{
    char comment[40];
    int nbpts;
    float *time;
    float *value;
} trace;

void simuTrace(int tmax, float dt, float params[], trace* uneTrace){
    int i = 0;
    float v = 0, w = 0, dv = 0, dw = 0, t = 0;
    int count = tmax/dt;
    uneTrace->time = malloc(count * sizeof(float));
    uneTrace->value = malloc(count * sizeof(float));
    while (i < count){
        dv = (params[0]-v)*(v-1)*v - w;
        dw = params[4]*(params[1]*v-params[2]*w-params[3]);
        v += dv*dt;
        w += dw*dt;
        uneTrace->time[i] = t;
        uneTrace->value[i] = v;
        i++;
        t += dt;
    }
    uneTrace->nbpts = i+1;
    strcpy(uneTrace->comment, "CommentaireDeLaTrace");
}
```

Comment: why set variable count = tmax/dt? explain me, pls?

Comment: Your loop increases `t` from `0` to `tmax` by `dt`. That means it performs `tmax/dt` iterations, so that's how many elements it will put into the arrays. Simple arithmetic.